# Create SparseTensor from a placeholder tensor?

Tags: tensorflow

I'd like to create a 2D Tensor whose rows are indicator vectors -- zeros, except for a one in a single column -- from input coming from a placeholder Tensor.
I've tried approaches like:

```
train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[64, 1])
...
tf.SparseTensor(
  indices=[[i, x] for i, x in enumerate(train_labels)],
  values=tf.ones(64),
  dense_shape=[64, 50000])
```

but Tensors aren't iterable. Does anyone have some direction?

Answer (score 0):

Working within tensor operations, I have an ugly prototype:

```
i = -1
def mk_pair(x):
    global i
    i = i+1
    c = tf.constant(i, dtype=tf.int64, shape=[1])
    x = tf.cast(x, tf.int64)
    return tf.concat([c, x], 0)

tf.SparseTensor(
    indices=tf.cast(tf.map_fn(mk_pair, train_labels), tf.int64),
    values=tf.ones(64),
    dense_shape=[64, 50000])
```